# How many subgroups of order 5 does $S_6$ have?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How many subgroups of order 5 does $S_6$ have?

There must be some theorem that I can use to find out the answer to this question, but I am coming up blank. I don't just want to know the answer, I'd like to know how you can figure it out. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know Sylow's theorems?

Comment: No we learn that at the end of the course :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, note that every prime-ordered (sub)group is cyclic, so this is *almost* equivalent to finding the total number of order-$5$ elements in $S_6$.  Each subgroup of order $5$ will have $4$ elements of order $5$ (per [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_theorem_(group_theory))) and will be disjoint sans the identity. How can we count the total number of elements of order $5$?

Every element in $S_n$ can be decomposed into a product of disjoint cycles.  Suppose some $\sigma \in S_n$ decomposes into disjoint cycles $\pi_1 \circ \pi_2 \circ \cdots \circ \pi_m$ of lengths $k_1, k_2, ..., k_m$.  Then one can prove that the order of $\sigma$ is equal to the least common multiple of the $k_i$'s.

Now let's think about the problem at hand.  Suppose a $\sigma \in S_6$ has order $5$.  This means, when decomposed into disjoint cycles, the least common multiple of the cycle lengths is $5$.  Meditate on when this is possible, and you'll be well on your way to an answer.

Comment: Nice answer, @Kaj Hansen.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, thank you!

Comment: Just to kind of wrap this up: I determined that $S_6$ has 144 elements of order 5. My intuition believes that the answer is then 144 subgroups, but after reading whats you wrote I cannot definitively say that this is true or not.

Comment: Careful @jgcello: some of those are going to belong to the *same subgroup*.  If you look at $\mathbb{Z}_5$ for example, every nonzero element of that group will generate it.  So if you want the total number of *subgroups*, finding the total number of order-$5$ elements is over-counting.  To correct for that, you'll need to divide your answer by $4$.